# Lipp imagine cache set files permissions 0600

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

After update Symfony to 3.0 Lipp Imagine generate thumbmails with permissions 0600

And can't be displayed in browser...

Anyone know how to help?

Comment: Read about the setacl commands here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually permission problems come with umask and/or bad configuration.

I did a bit of research for you and found a similar issue in the github repository for the bundle: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/326

What the say is basically you need to setup your umask in order to give the right permission to the group.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

LiipImagineBundle uses the `dumpFile()` method from the Symfony Filesystem component which introduced a regression in Symfony 3 leading to dumped files not getting the expected permissions (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14246 for the bug report and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17063 for the proposed patch).

Right now you cannot do much other than setting the permissions yourself after the files have been generated and wait for the fix to be released in Symfony 3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks. I added
`
if (strpos($filename,'media/cache') !== false) {
            $this->chmod($tmpFile, 0666, umask());
        }
`
To Symfony FIlesystem class ([link](https://github.com/symfony/filesystem/blob/master/Filesystem.php#L526))

Must suffice for now